# Lists to Dataframes with NA or 0

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe

I have a list with 138 tables in it `(prop.table)`. Each table can have up to 20 variables in it (numerical categories ranging from 11-95 as the colnames). I need to convert this list to a master dataframe. The first three tables look like  this:

```
[[1]]
x
        21         41         42         43         52         71         81         82 
0.02007456 0.58158876 0.22483510 0.09349011 0.05248064 0.01204474 0.00544881 0.01003728 

[[2]]
x
        21         41         42         43         52         71         90 
0.01175122 0.36973345 0.34107194 0.03066781 0.08655775 0.01633706 0.14388077 

[[3]]
x
         21          22          23          41          42 
0.043254082 0.008307075 0.016614151 0.930392438 0.001432254
```

I need to convert this to a matrix so it looks like this, with NAs or 0 when the categorical variable is not available:

```
x<-matrix (nrow=3, ncol=11 )
colnames(x) <-c('21', '22', '23', '41', '42', '43', '52', '71', '81', '82', '90' )
```

I have tried using this line from a previous similar question but the table is not correct:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(prop.table), nrow=138, byrow=T))
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue and get the table I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple way to using `lapply`, `rbind` and `do.call`

```
ptl
## [[1]]
## x
##         21         41         42         43         52         71         81         82 
## 0.02007456 0.58158876 0.22483510 0.09349011 0.05248064 0.01204474 0.00544881 0.01003728 
## 
## [[2]]
## x
##         21         41         42         43         52         71         90 
## 0.01175122 0.36973345 0.34107194 0.03066781 0.08655775 0.01633706 0.14388077 
## 
## [[3]]
## x
##          21          22          23          41          42 
## 0.043254082 0.008307075 0.016614151 0.930392438 0.001432254 
## 
## [[4]]
## x
##         21         22         31         41         42         43         81 
## 0.10028653 0.03123209 0.00487106 0.66103152 0.03037249 0.01604585 0.15616046 
## 
## [[5]]
## x
##           21           41           42           43           81 
## 0.0662080825 0.8291774147 0.0005732302 0.0865577529 0.0174835196 
## 
## [[6]]
## x
##          21          22          31          41          42          43          81 
## 0.081948424 0.002292264 0.006303725 0.825501433 0.029226361 0.020630372 0.034097421 
## 


# Get unique names of all columns in tables in the list
resCol <- unique(unlist(lapply(ptl, names)))

# Get dimensions of desired result
nresCol <- length(resCol)
nresRow <- length(ptl)

# Create 'Template' data.frame row
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(0, nresCol), nrow = 1, dimnames = list(1, resCol)))

# for every table in list, create copy of DF, fill it appropriately, then rbind result together using do.call

result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ptl, function(x) {
    retDF <- DF
    retDF[, names(x)] <- x
    return(retDF)
}))

# rename rows(optional)
rownames(result) <- 1:nrow(result)

result
##           21        41           42         43         52         71         81         82        90          22         23          31
## 1 0.02007456 0.5815888 0.2248351018 0.09349011 0.05248064 0.01204474 0.00544881 0.01003728 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
## 2 0.01175122 0.3697334 0.3410719404 0.03066781 0.08655775 0.01633706 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.1438808 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
## 3 0.04325408 0.9303924 0.0014322544 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.008307075 0.01661415 0.000000000
## 4 0.10028653 0.6610315 0.0303724928 0.01604585 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.15616046 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.031232092 0.00000000 0.004871060
## 5 0.06620808 0.8291774 0.0005732302 0.08655775 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.01748352 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
## 6 0.08194842 0.8255014 0.0292263610 0.02063037 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.03409742 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.002292264 0.00000000 0.006303725
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this is what you want?

```
x1 <- c(1, 5, 7)
names(x1) <- 1:3
x2 <- c(1, 2, 7)
names(x2) <- c(1,3,5)
l <- list(x1, x2)

m <- matrix(nrow=length(l), ncol=5)
colnames(m) <- 1:5
for (i in 1:length(l)) {
  m[i, names(l[[i]])] <- l[[i]]
}
```

Maybe one can replace the loop with an `apply` function, but I'm not sure...Basically, I loop through the list and set in every row of the matrix those columns that match with the names of the vector in the list.

Sorry for not using your data set, but you didn't have the code at hand and I was too lazy to type it out.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. This doesnt seem to work. Maybe because my `prop.table` object is a list with 138 different tables in it. I originally thought it was a list with 138 lists but it turns out they are tables.

Answer (score 2):

`rbind.fill` from the `plyr` package will do just this for you:

```
# make an example `prop.table`:
tbl <- 1:10
names(tbl) <- letters[1:10]
tbl <- as.matrix(tbl)

# make sure some of the columns are missing
prop.table <- list(tbl[sample(10, size=8),], tbl[sample(10, size=7),], tbl[sample(10, size=9),])
# [[1]]
# d b g c h f e i 
# 4 2 7 3 8 6 5 9 
# [[2]]
#  h  g  d  a  j  f  c 
#  8  7  4  1 10  6  3 
# [[3]]
#  c  i  b  d  j  a  h  g  e 
# 3  9  2  4 10  1  8  7  5
```

You can use the `rbind.fill` function from `plyr`, which is just `rbind` but it fills missing columns out with `NA`. It can take in a list of data frames to `rbind` together, so I convert each element of `prop.table` into a dataframe first (needed the `t` to ensure each `prop.table[[i]]` was treated as a row, not a column)

```
rbind.fill(lapply(prop.table, function (x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
#   d  b g c h  f  e  i  a  j
# 1 4  2 7 3 8  6  5  9 NA NA
# 2 4 NA 7 3 8  6 NA NA  1 10
# 3 4  2 7 3 8 NA  5  9  1 10
```

(Note - you can sort the columns of the output dataframe with `x[, order(colnames(x))]`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to suggest one solution.  How about you just concatenate all of the lists in one.  So you would have

```
MyDataFrame
variable1         1          1          1          1          1          1          1          1
variable2        21         41         42         43         52         71         81         82 
variable30.02007456 0.58158876 0.22483510 0.09349011 0.05248064 0.01204474 0.00544881 0.01003728 

variable1         2          2          2          2          2          2          2 
variable2        21         41         42         43         52         71         90 
variable30.01175122 0.36973345 0.34107194 0.03066781 0.08655775 0.01633706 0.14388077 

variable1          3           3           3           3           3
variable2         21          22          23          41          42 
variable30.043254082 0.008307075 0.016614151 0.930392438 0.001432254
```

And once you have only one data frame.  You can use the reshape function.  like

```
install.packages('reshape')
library('reshape')
cast(MyDataFrame, variable1~variable2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't be the most efficient, but using `plyr` and `reshape2`, and assuming your list of `prop.tables` is called `foo`

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)


allData <- dcast(ldply(lapply(seq_along(foo), function(x) data.frame(foo[[x]], id = x))), 
                id ~ x, value.var = 'Freq')
```

or more straight forwardly

```
ff <- c('21', '22', '23', '41', '42', '43', '52', '71', '81', '82', '90' )

t(sapply(foo, function(x,y) {x[ff]} ))
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. This doesnt seem to work. Maybe because my `prop.table` object is a list with 138 different tables in it. I originally thought it was a list with 138 lists but it turns out they are tables.

Comment: @IDelToro -- make your question reproducible by including `dput(head(prop.table.list))` (where `prop.table.list` is your list of prop tables

Comment: `prop.table.list<-lapply(Landcover, function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
dput(head(prop.table.list))`

Comment: You save the day, yet again :) Cheers mate!